# Is suppression of the Arcane effect permanent over time?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

As far as I know the Arcane background in Mage: The Ascension did not mention the ability to "suppress" the effect of Arcane (i.e. people being unable to track/remember the Mage in question). However, the Unofficial Wiki (link below) expressly states that it is possible.

At the risk of "Primarily Opinion Based" I am wondering if that suppression is momentary or long term?

**Example:** 
If the Mage wants their friend to remember them when they meet for coffee. The Mage suppresses the effect ONCE for the duration of the coffee. The next time they meet, will the friend remember the Mage?

On the one hand it may be possible (with low levels of Arcane) to suppress it one time, thereby creating a "permanent" memory imprint, and not have to continue doing it for those individuals again and again (leave it "up" all the time).

Like an idiot I forgot the Wiki link -.-
[Mage: The Ascension glossary - Arcane](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Arcane)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functional effect of Arcane is to boost Stealth rolls and penalize Investigation and Perception checks. The other stuff is mainly for roleplaying color; your friends will remember you unless you and your Storyteller think it's more dramatic or funny if they don't — and even then, that's at Arcane 4 or 5.

Since you can dampen it at will, it makes sense that you can do so for as long as you like in a given scene. If you'd like to have them remember you at the start of a new scene, just do so at the beginning.

Comment: Jadasc,
Thank you for the response. This is a long-standing question on many WoD chats and I figured it was worth posting here.